# How do I change the data from daily to monthly using panda datareader in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to pull companies and their data off of yahoo finance and get the end of the month adjusted closing price for all the tickers that I input. I have figured out this much by using the internet but I cannot figure out if there is a parameter in datareader that allows me to sort the data by month instead of day. Here is my current code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data

# Define the instruments to download. We would like to see Apple, Microsoft and the S&P500 index.
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', '^GSPC']

# We would like all available data from 01/01/2010 until 12/31/2016.
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'

# User pandas_reader.data.DataReader to load the desired data. As simple as that.
test = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)['Adj Close']

print(test)
```

This prints out:

```
Symbols           AAPL       MSFT        ^GSPC
Date                                          
2010-01-04   26.466835  24.294369  1132.989990
2010-01-05   26.512596  24.302216  1136.520020
2010-01-06   26.090879  24.153070  1137.140015
2010-01-07   26.042646  23.901886  1141.689941
2010-01-08   26.215786  24.066734  1144.979980
...                ...        ...          ...
2016-12-23  110.743988  59.756943  2263.790039
2016-12-27  111.447319  59.794735  2268.879883
2016-12-28  110.972122  59.520710  2249.919922
2016-12-29  110.943588  59.435673  2249.260010
2016-12-30  110.078697  58.717522  2238.830078

[1762 rows x 3 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The information is correct but I want it so that it only prints out monthly data instead of each day.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: NEW CODE v2

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import datetime
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# Converts excel file into a dataframe for python to use
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Test\Downloads\SP_500.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Symbol'])
products_list = df.values.tolist()

# Removes list inside of lists and formats the . to -
output = (list(chain(*products_list)))
t = [x.replace('.', '-') for x in output]

start = datetime.date(2014,12,31)  # '2014-12-31'
end = datetime.date(2020,1,31) # '2020-01-01'

tickers = Ticker(t, asynchronus=True)

# Check if everything is True
x = tickers.validation
print(Counter(x.values()))

df = tickers.history(start=start, end=end, interval='1mo')


df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='symbol', values='adjclose')


# Exports the values into an excel file
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Summer Research\SP500_Adj_Close.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: If you want a monthly data, I think you have to apply some kind of aggregation, otherwise how does the DataFrame knows what to return?